# Make apostrophe closer to letter

Tags: typography, kerning, lettrine, drop-cap

I am using the `lettrine` package to typeset capitals. When there is an apostrophe with a capital L, the spaces look quite ugly. I would like to achieve something like the following:

[image: target capital]

I've already set some parameters of the capital to get close to it:

```
\lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,lraise=0,loversize=0.15,findent=-1em,nindent=1.5em]{L'}{Esprit-Saint}
```

but the apostrophe is too far from the capital L. I've tried using `\kern` to get it closer, but I'm not getting anywhere really. Is there a way I can get the apostrophe aligned like in the given example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lettrine,blindtext}
\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=0.33,lraise=0,loversize=0.15,
  nindent=1.5em]{L\kern-5pt'}{Esprit-Saint}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the apostrophe works better if placed thus: `\lettrine[...]{L\kern-5pt}{'Esprit-Saint}`, since then it is in the natural size, as in the example of the OP.  Also, is the `loversize` intended to make the top of the L level with the first line of text?  I keep getting font size substitutions so I can't see what's going on (I know nothing about dealing with fonts in TeX, so I can't help this).

Comment: Whether the apostrophe should be part of the capital or the small caps text is subject to debate. In my case, the apostrophe looks quite ugly if I put it in the small caps, so I chose to put it with the lettrine.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to push back the apostrophe, precede it by

```
\kern-.3em
```

or something and maybe add some kern after it. That is

```
\lettrine[...]{L\kern-.3em'\kern.1em}{Esprit-Saint}
```

It obviously depends on the font. I would let the apostrophe where it goes, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where the apostrophe goes is a bit ugly in the lettrine, as it makes a huge blank square between the L's vertical bar and the small capitals. I've read on a typography forum that it was a better idea to try and align it as shown in my question.