# Lettrine package and the letter L

Tags: lettrine, drop-cap

I am using the package `lettrine` to typeset capitals. In the documentation there are some special parameters to get the text closer in certain letter. For example, with the `A` you can set up lettrine to follow the inclination of the letter. Same with the `V` and other examples. What I would like is to get the text closer in the `L`.

To make it clear. I get the following:

[image]

and I would like this:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: Did you try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20082/make-apostrophe-closer-to-letter ?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @egreg: it is not the same, notice that in the example of that question the capital letter covers only 2 lines, so it is possible to control with findent. Here it is not the case.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I asked the exact same question yesterday: [Make apostrophe closer to letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20082/make-apostrophe-closer-to-letter)

**With the apostrophe in dropcap**

This was my initial attempt, playing with `\kern` to adjust the apostrophe back inside the capital L:

```
\lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,lraise=0,loversize=0.15]%
  {L\kern-12pt{'}}{objectif}
```

In my case, this setting gives me this:

[image: L lettrine with apostrophe]

**Your request: apostrophe in small caps**

I have chosen to include the apostrophe in the lettrine. Whether this is good practice is subject to [debate among French typographists](https://listes.irisa.fr/wws/arc/typographie/2008-11/msg00231.html). If you wish to keep the apostroph in the text and get the text inside the lettrine as in your example, you can use the `findent` and `nindent` parameters of the lettrine instead.

For example, with:

```
\lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,lraise=0,loversize=0.15,findent=-0.7em,nindent=1em]%
   {L}{'Esprit-Saint ...}
```

I get the following:

[image: Lettrine using nindent]

**Using slope to achieve the exact result you desire**

In the previous example, I used `nindent` but this put the second and third lines to the right of the dropcap. In your example, you wanted the second line in the L and the third line to its right. You can achieve that by using `slope` instead of `nindent`, although that work with 3 lines (as in your situation).

```
\lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,lraise=0,loversize=0.15,findent=-0.7em,slope=0.5em]%
   {L}{'Esprit-Saint ...}
```

gives me:

[image: Lettrine using slope]

**Adjusting oversize to align on top**

Finally, you might want to adjust the `oversize` parameter so the top of the lettrine fits with the apostrophe.

```
\lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,lraise=0,loversize=0.08,findent=-0.9em,slope=0.5em]%
   {L}{'Esprit-Saint ...}
```

[image: Lettrine with slope and adjusted oversize]

You'll have to adapt the values to your own font.

**Note:**

After doing all this, I actually settled for this last solution for my own document, instead of the first solution I gave above.

**Hint:**

To make things easier, to can add your defaults to a local `lettrine.cfg` file, for example:

```
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}                                                    
%%                                                                              
%% These are *decimal* numbers:                                                 
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.25}                                          
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0}                                                
\renewcommand{\DefaultLhang}{0.33}                                              
% Define default options per letter                                             
\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{optfile.cfl}
```

and then you can set the default options per letter in `optfile.cfl`:

```
% options per letter                                                            
\LettrineOptionsFor{A}{slope=5pt,findent=-0.5em}                                
\LettrineOptionsFor{J}{lraise=0.20,nindent=0em}                                 
\LettrineOptionsFor{L}{lraise=0,loversize=0.08,findent=-0.9em,nindent=1em}      
\LettrineOptionsFor{P}{findent=0.1em,nindent=0.1em}                             
\LettrineOptionsFor{Q}{lraise=0.30,loversize=0.15}
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree it could be OK to put the apostrophe in the lettrine, however this is a text mainly in English, where just the abstract is in French, so it would look a bit odd to have the apostrophe also big (specially because in the same page it is the abstract in English, which starts with "The", so I prefer your second solution).